# How to setup the ssl certificates in keycloak and tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat8

I have purchased the ssl certificate from the third party vendor. They have provide three files as mentioned below.

1) Certificate.crt,
2) ca_bundle.crt,
3)  private.key.

I want to install above three files in keycloak and tomcat server.

How to convert above three files as myserver.jks file ?

Please help on this.

I am new to this

Answer (score 1):

The .jks is not a certificate file but a keystore. You can [import the certificate](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Importing_the_Certificate) using the `keytool`. You should be following the [SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Create_a_local_Certificate_Signing_Request_(CSR)) in order to understand what you are doing, and why.

Usually you don't get the key from the CA, but [create a CSR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Create_a_local_Certificate_Signing_Request_(CSR)) for them to sign. That way the vendor doesn't have access to your private key, which is an important security measure; despite they have granted you the certificate after validating you own the domain, they won't be able to decrypt your connections.

You can't import the key directly using the `keytool`, but you must convert the certificate and the private key into a PKCS 12 file first:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private.key -name hostname -out cert-with-the-key.p12
```

Then, you can import it and the CA bundle:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [password] -destkeystore myserver.jks -srckeystore cert-with-the-key.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12

keytool -import -alias bundle -trustcacerts -file ca_bundle.crt -keystore myserver.jks
```

Comment: Hi Jokinen,Thank you for the valid information and i have done Jks creation is working fine..